# Show that $(x'Ay)x=(xx'A)y$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, symmetry, positive-definite

> Suppose $x,y$ are vectors and $A$ is a symmetric invertible matrix. Show that $(x'Ay)x=(xx'A)y$.

How can one prove the above? I am aware that matrix multiplication is not necessarily associative. But it seems associativity has been used here.

> Is it true that $\dfrac{(A^{1/2}xx'A^{1/2})x}{x'Ax}=x$? Here $x$ is a vector, and $A$ is a symmetric pd matrix.

I think this is true and "somehow" follows from the previous result. But how does it follow?

Comment: Maybe you can use index notation to prove this. What does x' mean ? the derivative of the x components with respect to the variable ? (x′Ay)x is a vector ?

Comment: @JulienRoussillon x' is $x^{T}$ ?

Comment: Certainly yes !

Comment: $x'$ is $x^T$. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

1. $x'Ay$ is a scalar. Hence

$$(x'Ay)x = x(x'Ay)$$

2. If $x =0$,

the result is obvious.

O/w,

$x'Ax$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{1/2}xx'A^{1/2}$.

This can be seen by defining $a := (x'A^{1/2})'$ s.t.

$$A^{1/2}xx'A^{1/2} = (x'A^{1/2})'x'A^{1/2} = aa'$$

$$x'Ax = x'A^{1/2}A^{1/2}x = (A^{1/2}x)'(A^{1/2}x) = aa'$$

Is $a'a$ an eigenvalue of $aa'$? [I believe so](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=49AdCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA100&lpg=PA100&dq=eigenvalue%20of%20xx%27%20is%20x%27x&source=bl&ots=DCXOjB1xQq&sig=OtSX6gGEkJL3vST4qRYHzBq1eQo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQw9rp8LbLAhUlqqYKHU_iBwEQ6AEIMDAD#v=onepage&q=eigenvalue%20of%20xx'%20is%20x'x&f=false). Corresponding eigenvector is $x = a$ as can be seen with:

$$(aa')a = (a'a)a$$

which follows the same idea as in #1.

Comment: I still don't see why 2. holds.

Comment: @LandonCarter Oh sorry. I realized the LHS is matrix * vector while RHS would be x'Ax x (scalar * vector). Probably an eigenvalue. Edited